# Как преобразовать строку с правами доступа обратно в число?

Tags: python, chmod

Есть такая замечательная функция [stat.filemode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html#stat.filemode), которая преобразует мутное число, описывающее права доступа к файлу, в простую и понятную строку:

```
>>> os.stat('test.txt').st_mode
35248
>>> oct(os.stat('test.txt').st_mode)
'0o104660'
>>> stat.filemode(os.stat('test.txt').st_mode)
'-rwSrw----'
```

А вот функции получения числа обратно из этой строки я там что-то не обнаружил. Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение, чтоб не велосипедить?

Comment: Вроде тут есть ответ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099181/how-to-get-from-rw-r-r-back-to-33188

Comment: @super16 и правда, но залезать в привватную переменную как-то не очень красиво